# Error when passing variable to apollo query

Tags: reactjs, apollo, react-apollo, graphql-js

Created an Apollo Query similar to this [example](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/queries#data) but keep getting this error: `Variable "$id" of required type "ID!" was not provided.`

My schema:

```
type RootQuery {
    person(_id: ID!): Person!
}
```

and resolver:

```
 person: async args => {
    const person = await Person.findById(args._id);
    return {
      _id: person._id,
      name: person.name,
      location: person.location,
      address: person.address,
    };
  }
```

which works normally in `localhost:3000/graphql`
I'm passing an id and getting back the data.

Yet, it doesn't work on the client side, the error says the id isn't provided.

query

```
const GET_PERSON_QUERY = gql`
  query person($id: ID!) {
    person(_id: $id) {
      _id
      name
      location
      address
    }
  }
`;
```

Query Component

```
export const GetPerson = ({ _id }) => {
  console.log("id: ", _id);
  return (
    <Query query={GET_PERSON_QUERY} variables={{ _id }}>
      {({ loading, error, data }) => {
        if (error) return <div>Error loading posts</div>;
        if (loading) return <div>Loading...</div>
          );
        return (
          <ul>
            <li>{data.person.name}</li>

          </ul>
        );
      }}
    </Query>
  );
};
```

For example, passing this variable `const _id = "abcabc"` to the component
`<GetPerson _id={_id}` /> results in error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error indicates, `id` is a required variable but you are not passing it in. This is your code, which uses property shorthand syntax:

```
<Query query={GET_PERSON_QUERY} variables={{ _id }}>
```

This is equivalent to:

```
<Query query={GET_PERSON_QUERY} variables={{ _id: _id }}>
```

So you are providing a variable named `_id`, not `id`. Change your variables prop to:

```
<Query query={GET_PERSON_QUERY} variables={{ id: _id }}>
```